# How to optimize too slow SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, query-optimization

I need my query to run weekly, but it is taking very long (about one hour per execution). The sheer volume of information makes it long to run, but I wondered how I could optimize it. I'm an SQL novice. This is my request :

```
SELECT PRIME_MINISTER.PRIME_MINISTER_ID,
       PRIME_MINISTER.PRIME_MINISTER_NAME,
       CITY.CITY_ID,
       CITY.CITY_POPULATION,
       CITY.CITY_FOUNDATION_DATE,
       STATE.STATE_ID,
       STATE.STATE_NAME,
       CITY_ACCOUNTANT.CITY_ACCOUNTANT_ID,
       CITY_ACCOUNTANT.CITY_ACCOUNTANT_SOCIAL,
       CITY_ACCOUNTANT.CITY_ACCOUNTANT_NAME,
       CITY_COUNCIL.CITY_COUNCIL_ID,
       CITY_COUNCIL.CITY_COUNCIL_FREQUENCY,
       CITY_DEBT.CITY_DEBT_ID,
       CITY_DEBT.CITY_DEBT_NATURE,
       CITY_DEBT.CITY_DEBT_AMOUNT,
       HEAD_OF_STATE.HEAD_OF_STATE_ID,
       HEAD_OF_STATE.HEAD_OF_STATE_SOCIAL,
       DEPUTY_HEAD_OF_STATE.DEPUTY_HEAD_OF_STATE_ID,
       DEPUTY_HEAD_OF_STATE.DEPUTY_HEAD_OF_STATE_SOCIAL,
       DEPUTY_HEAD_OF_STATE.DEPUTY_HEAD_OF_STATE_NAME
FROM CITY
LEFT JOIN CITY_COUNCIL ON CITY.CITY_ID = CITY_COUNCIL.CITY_ID
LEFT JOIN CITY_DEBT ON CITY_COUNCIL.CITY_COUNCIL_ID = CITY_DEBT.CITY_COUNCIL_ID
OR CITY.CITY_ID = CITY_DEBT.CITY_ID
INNER JOIN CITY_ACCOUNTANT ON CITY_ACCOUNTANT.CITY_ACCOUNTANT_ID = CITY.CITY_ACCOUNTANT_ID
INNER JOIN STATE ON STATE.STATE_ID = CITY.STATE_ID
INNER JOIN HEAD_OF_STATE ON HEAD_OF_STATE.HEAD_OF_STATE_ID = STATE.HEAD_OF_STATE_ID
INNER JOIN DEPUTY_HEAD_OF_STATE ON DEPUTY_HEAD_OF_STATE.DEPUTY_HEAD_OF_STATE_ID = HEAD_OF_STATE.DEPUTY_HEAD_OF_STATE_ID
INNER JOIN PRIME_MINISTER ON STATE.STATE_ID = PRIME_MINISTER.STATE_ID
WHERE CITY.CITY_STATUS = 2
  AND CITY.PRIME_MINISTER_STATUS = 2
  AND CITY.JURISDICTION = '70'
  AND CITY.CITY_ACCOUNTANT_NATURE = 'S'
ORDER BY DEPUTY_HEAD_OF_STATE.DEPUTY_HEAD_OF_STATE_ID,
         HEAD_OF_STATE.HEAD_OF_STATE_ID,
         STATE.STATE_ID,
         CITY.CITY_ID,
         CITY_COUNCIL.CITY_COUNCIL_ID,
         CITY_DEBT.CITY_DEBT_ID,
         CITY_ACCOUNTANT.CITY_ACCOUNTANT_ID;
```

I select all of this data in the reading part of a spring batch to be able to write it in a file.

This is the database model :
[Database Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8X8F.png)

The database is not mine so I can't modify the database model but I can create indexes if needed.
There is between 1,000 and 7,000 rows selected per execution. All the columns are needed.

Comment: Could you share the execution plan (with predicates) so we can have an idea of where your time might be going. Make sure you sanity check it too, is it doing what you’d expect. How much data is there that needs to be read?

Comment: What constitutes "a lot of modifications"? Can you create or recommend the creation of appropriate indexes? It's a pretty simple query so I don't think there's much to be done on that side.

Comment: One of the joins is on a compound condition using `or`. That may be a bottleneck. To give us more information to work with, please modify the query as follows: run it once with only one of the two conditions in that join; then run it again, using only the **other** condition in the join. If both these modified queries run significantly faster, there may be something you can do about it. Just let us know either way.

Comment: Other than that, the query is very basic. It may be that there's nothing you can do. It is also possible that certain indexes would help (if they don't exist already, or if the optimizer doesn't use them for some reason - that would have to be investigated). A common reason for the optimizer to make bad choices is that current statistics on the referenced tables aren't available. You may ask the DBA to make sure that statistics are gathered on those tables. (It doesn't matter if you don't understand what that means; the DBA will.) Ask them about indexes at the same time - are there any?

Comment: I'm not able to give you the execution plan, I don't have access to the data so the query isn't executed on my machine. It is doing what it is meant to though.

Comment: I will look into the indexes that are on the database, and for the `or` in the join. I'll let you know.

Comment: How many cities are there, and how many meet all the selection criteria? What is the largest table? I'd guess `city_debt`, in which case you might try indexing `city_council_id` and `city_id`. (`city_debt.city_council_id` doesn't appear on the diagram by the way, not sure if that matters.)

Answer (score 1):

- `CITY_ACCOUTANT` in SQL vs `CITY_ACCOUNTANT` in picture: is this the right query or a typo?
- Is the spring batch process is taking an hour or just the query?

Comment: The typo is corrected. The names aren't really important though, they're not the real names from my database.
It's the query in itself that takes an hour

Comment: Without plan, one way is to run the query with one join (just city join with  city_council) check the performance and join the next table and repeat it till you find any problem. You can also if optimizer hints can be used with caution*.